# Rudin, Perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I have a question about this proof in baby Rudin's text.  I post the picture and my question below.

[image]

From what I understand of this proof, $V_n$ is a neighborhood of the point $x_n$ listed above in the beginning, and by construction, all the points $ x_n \in V_1 $ for $ n = 2,3,....$. But how do we know that all the point of $P$ will be contained in some neighborhood of $x_1$, since this would mean that the set $P$ is bounded but perfect sets doesn't implies boundedness.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not true that all points of $P$ are contained in $V_1$. However, since $P$ is perfect and $x_1 \in V_1$, infinitely many other points of $P$ must be in $V_1$. This is all he needs.

Comment: @NoahOlander Thank you for your reply. I know that the $V_1$ contains infinitely many points but how do we know that it will contain $x_2$, $ x_3$ and so on since it contain some infinitely many points like $ x_9, x_{11},..$ but it doesn't mean that it contains all the points as listed in the beginning of the proof.  I'm sorry if I misunderstand your idea.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily contain $x_2, x_3, \dots $ though. That's what my comment says. He never assumes that $V_1$ contains $P$.

Comment: @NoahOlander wait, but $V_n$ is the neighborhood of the point $x_n$ where $x_n$ is listed above right?  if not, then if $x_2 $ is not in $V_1$, then  $V_2$ is the neighborhood of what point though? I'm sorry but I just don't understand his set up of the proof.

Comment: No, $V_n$ are neighborhoods, and they contain some $x_k$, but they do not necessarily contain $x_n$. I can see why you might think that, but if you read carefully, it only says the $V_n$ are neighborhoods (in Rudin's terminology, a neighborhood is a ball), it never says $V_n$ is a neighborhood of $x_n$.

Comment: @NoahOlander Oh, I see.  I think I understand his set up now.  Thank you very much for your help!!